# LinqToTwitter v5.1.2 AspNetAuthorizer doesn't contains a definition for CredentialStore

Tags: asp.net, twitter, linq-to-twitter

In my website .Net Framework 4.8, when I update from LinqToTwitter v5.1.1 to 5.1.2 I get an error message when I try to create a new instance of AspNetAuthorizer saying:

> "AspNetAuthorizer doesn't contains a definition for CredentialStore"
> and "AuthorizeBase is defined in an assembly is not referenced. You
> must add a reference to assembly 'LinqToTwitter.netstandard, Version
> =5.1.2.0"

Code Example:

```
return new AspNetAuthorizer
{
    CredentialStore = new SessionStateCredentialStore
    {
        ConsumerKey = MyKey,
        ConsumerSecret = Secret
    },
    GoToTwitterAuthorization =
        twitterUrl => url
};
```

I tried to add a using and searched for the package "LinqToTwitter.netstandard" in nuget but doesn't exists.

Is this version broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug caused by LINQ to Twitter, which has since been fixed and deployed. Here's the fixed/closed issue on the LINQ to Twitter site:

https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/issues/200